# how to convert this jquery into javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using this jquery code and I want to convert this into javascript. I have recently started javascript and I have a little knowledge in jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".row a").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".imgBox img ").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I always thought that jQuery *was* JavaScript... Anyway, can you provide the HTML on which this script is applied?

Comment: You can do an online search for these jQuery functions, like "jQuery function *x* in vanilla Javascript"

Comment: This is another useful resource: https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/move-from-jquery-to-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: My favorite tool to find the JavaScript equivalent is https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/, but it's not an automatic tool, and you need to know some JavaScript in order to convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent in vanilla JavaScript is (I added some HTML to make it work):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelectorAll(".row a").forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.querySelector(".imgBox img").src = elem.href;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x120/000/fff">link 1</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <a href="https://dummyimage.com/600x120/00f/f88">link 2</a>
</div>
<div class="imgBox"><img src=""/></div>
```

Comment: Can you explain this code part by part Im new to js

Comment: It does what your jQuery code did - so that should explain what this code does? All these methods are explained on mdn: [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 0):

Following instruction from this cheatsheet:
https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/move-from-jquery-to-vanilla-javascript/

```
const ready = (callback) => {
  if (document.readyState != "loading") callback();
  else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
}

ready(() => { 
  /* Do things after DOM has fully loaded */
  document.querySelector(".row a").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector(".imgBox img ").setAttribute('src', document.querySelector(".imgBox img ").getAttribute('href));
  });
});
```

Comment: use `const` in place of `var`. Let's no spread bad practices :)

Comment: @CristianTraìna fair enough, answer edited